# Passing multiple string params to Javascript using Eval in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass more than one parameter to JavaScript function from within asp.net. I tried this solution but it doesn't work when the parameter is string if I replace the string param with another one integer it works properly:

```
onClick: '<%# String.Format("test({0},{1})", Eval("O1"),Eval("hometeam")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add double quote "" around the {X} of your string parameter, like this

```
    <input id = "btn_o2" type ="button" style = "width :40px ; height : 18px ;font-size :8 ; height : 18px ;font-size :8" value = '<%# Eval("o2") %>' onclick = '<%# String.Format("addTicket({0},""{1}"")", Eval("O1"),Eval("hometeam")) %>' />
```

Comment: didn't you forget something ?!